# Injecting beans and values (as defined in context.xml) into servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm trying to inject a Spring-managed bean and a string value into a servlet. The servlet is defined in `context.xml` as following:

```
<bean name="gwtlogging" class="com.somepackage.MyRemoteLogger">
    <property name="symbolMapsDirectory" value="/WEB-INF/deploy/gwt/symbolMaps/"/>
    <property name="serializationPolicyResolver" ref="serializationPolicyResolver"/>
</bean>
```

I came across using this method:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
            config.getServletContext());
}
```

This works, but has some disadvantages:

- I want to inject beans as defined in `context.xml` and not per autowiring
- I need to inject a string value (not a bean), which seems impossible this way

Ideally I want that all values defined in xml will be somehow injected into servlet instance.

Comment: Please clarify _I want to inject beans as defined in context.xml and not per autowiring_.

Comment: Well, autowiring injects instances based on name, type, etc. I want them to be injected as it's stated in xml.

Comment: Is `MyRemoteLogger` a `Servlet`?

Comment: Correct, sorry I didn't mention it

Comment: The main problem is the second one, injecting a static value. I can leave with autowiring, but I need this string injected.

Comment: Ok, so the whole problem is that your `context.xml` is a Spring managed configuration. Beans are Spring managed. Servlets, on the other hand, are managed by your Servlet container. So the `gwtlogging` bean declared in your XML will not be the same **instance** as a `<servlet>` of type `com.somepackage.MyRemoteLogger`  declared in your web.xml, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If it's available to you, you can declare a `Servlet` bean in your XML configuration file, use Spring's [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) (or write your own [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html)) to load the XML file in a `WebApplicationContext`, retrieve the `Servlet` bean, and add it to the `ServletContext` with [`add(String, Servlet)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet%28java.lang.String,%20javax.servlet.Servlet%29).

The `Servlet` instance will have been completely prepared through Spring and will be used by your Servlet container.

Comment: I didn't get why I should load xml again, if I there is already `ApplicationContext` available in my servlet? Can I just add servlet instance to a spring context, will it inject values then?

Comment: @damluar In this example, there isn't a second `ApplicationContext`. This is the only one you load. It's an alternative to the one loaded in web.xml. See the javadoc for an example.